# Keeping ons-sliding-menu open?

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm currently working on an Onsen-based application where the requirement is that the sliding menu stay open.

It works okay by setting "*swipeable=false*" in conjunction with manually opening the sliding menu via "*application.slidingmenu.open()*", but my issue is that there appears to be a click event bound somewhere that auto-closes the sliding-menu every time a click event is registered outside the sliding-menu (in the page body etc).

Anyone have any pointers?

**Update**: I went another route - by using `ons-split-view` ([see official docs](https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons-split-view.html)):

Essentialy, it's:

```
<ons-sliding-menu 
ng-show="isMobile"
var="application.slidingmenu"
swipe-target-width="100"
main-page="page1.html" 
menu-page="menu.html"
side="left" 
max-slide-distance="250px">
```

```
<ons-split-view
ng-show="!isMobile"
secondary-page="menu.html"
main-page="page1.html"
main-page-width="85%"
collapse="portrait">
```

Comment: There is a mask that has a click event listener. Just remove the mask element.